# Conflicting Python versions in SageMaker Studio notebook with Python 3.8 kernel

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker, anaconda3

I'm trying to run a SageMaker kernel with Python 3.8 in SageMaker Studio, and the notebook appears to use a separate distribution of Python 3.7. The *running app* is indicated as *tensorflow-2.6-cpu-py38-ubuntu20.04-v1*. When I run `!python3 -V` I get *Python 3.8.2*. However, the Python instance inside the notebook is different:

```
import sys
sys.version
```

gives `'3.7.12 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Oct 26 2021, 06:08:21) \n[GCC 9.4.0]'`

Similarly, running `%pip -V` and `%conda info` indicates Python 3.7.

Also, `import tensorflow` fails, as it isn't preinstalled in the Python environment that the notebook invokes.

I'm running in the *eu-west-2* region. Is there anything I can do to address this short of opening a support ticket?

Comment: I have just solved this and can answer. Which python instance do you want though - 3.8 or conda 3.7?

Comment: Not sure as I'm no longer working on this project. @jtlz2 please share what worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you still facing this issue?

I am in eu-west-2 using a SageMaker Studio notebook and the TensorFlow 2.6 Python 3.8 CPU Optimized image (running app is tensorflow-2.6-cpu-py38-ubuntu20.04-v1).

When I run the below commands, I get the right outputs.

```
!python3 -V
```

returns Python 3.8.2

```
import sys
sys.version
```

returns
3.8.2 (default, Dec  9 2021, 06:26:16) \n[GCC 9.3.0]'

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

returns 2.6.2

It seems this has now been fixed