# AWS Sagemaker Studio JupyterLab Space: Glue Pyspark and Ray Kernel Python and pip version mismatch

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-sagemaker, jupyter-lab, amazon-sagemaker-studio

It looks like there is a discrepancy between the Python version and the pip-installed packages in my Glue Pyspark and Ray kernel in my AWS Sagemaker Studio JupyterLab Space. I first noticed the issue when I was trying to import IPython, by which I received a `ModuleNotFound` Error, but if I did `!pip list | grep ipython` I get ipython 8.20.0. I also did `!ipython --version` which gives 8.20.0.

Upon further investigation, I did the following.

## 1. With the Glue Pyspark and Ray kernel

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

which gives

`['/tmp', '/tmp/spark-7a070785-711d-4791-9ed3-631d12bc29a0/userFiles-298f6845-dc16-4a6c-95e2-0245bbc35529', '/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip', '/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip', '/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python37.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.7', '/usr/lib64/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages']`

`!python --version` however gives 3.10.13

I also did `pandas.__version__` which gives 1.3.2, but `!pip list | grep pandas` gives

pandas                                2.1.4
pandas-stubs                          2.1.4.231227

## 2. With the standard Python 3 (ipykernel)

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

which gives

`['/home/sagemaker-user', '/opt/conda/lib/python310.zip', '/opt/conda/lib/python3.10', '/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '', '/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages']`

and `!python --version` now gives 3.10.13, which is consistent with `sys.path`

I redid `pandas.__version__` which now gives 2.1.4, while `!pip list | grep pandas` gives

pandas                                2.1.4
pandas-stubs                          2.1.4.231227

which is consistent.

## 3. Conclusion

It therefore seems I have an issue with the Glue Pyspark and Ray kernel where the Python version in the kernel is pointing to some other installation than the one recognized by pip, and therefore many of the pip-installed packages are not found.

I did find a similar question posted here [Conflicting Python versions in SageMaker Studio notebook with Python 3.8 kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70486162/conflicting-python-versions-in-sagemaker-studio-notebook-with-python-3-8-kernel) but the accepted answer isn't really helping me.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Am I missing something simple here or has anyone else come across such an issue with the Glue Pyspark and Ray kernel?

UPDATE: I've created an issue [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-feedback/issues/57) as well. The team is aware of it and will update once a fix has been implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the same issue. I was not able to install additional packages to "Glue PySpark and Ray" environment by normal approaches.

As a workaround, I found it is still possible to install additional packages by executing Python code as below:

```
import pip
pip.main(['install', "ipython"])
```

I would like to report this issue to the team.

Comment: Hi Tomonori, thanks for the workaround. Please see my updated post, the team is now aware of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can install additional packages to the Glue PySpark and Ray kernel by running following magic command before running other Python cells.

`%additional_python_modules pandas`

See also : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/interactive-sessions-magics.html